# lat lng distances automated from fixed positions to lan lng in database ( australia )

Tags: mysql, geolocation

Ok this is a big ask, I have been reading a lot about this on here and over the tinternet.

The best I have found is : [this link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Now Here is our issue ( this is just for Australian distances ) 
We have a database of lat and lng values for every single suburb in Australia.

My question is ... is there a way we could run some kind of script pinging our servers, and storing the results in a large db.

So a bit like:

record a: lat lng -> record b: lat lng ( do calculation and store distance in record )
record a: lat lng -> record b: lat lng ( do calculation and store distance in record )

and so on ( and do not do record b: lat lng -> record a: lat lng ( as this is already known )

At the moment the easiest way of accessing this data is via real world names such as suburb state and postcode, which we have within the db along with the lat lng values.

Those are really superfluous as each data entry has an id. similar to my example above.

The objective is to get :

ID 1 -> ID2 distance =:75 km

Where ID1 = -27.4561899, 153.3564564 ( known name Raby Bay QLD 4163 )
and   ID2 = -27.1054534, 152.948145  ( known name Morayfield QLD 4560 )

do you get where I am going with this...

So my question is does anyone know of a way we can run an automated script, that will grab the ID then the next ID record and perform a function and save the result to the db and then do the next ... so on and so forth.

We have extremely fast servers, and there are some 13000 individual records ( suburbs ) for us to pit against each other..

Which will give us approximately 84,506,500 results ( .ish )

obviously we would need to do calculations for the same ID because then we can echo 0 km

So any suggestions, has anyone seen or done anything like this before ??

Is there a better way, we would ideally like to do this server side ( and store results ) then spew them out on page load...

Because this is for members site and advertised items.. so we know:

Advertisers location and Vistiors location so would want to spew out the distance from buyer to seller on the fly. Without running large client side code.

Ste

Answer (score 2):

The calculations are not really that difficult -- certainly not worth precomputing 84M+ rows in a table, where almost certainly very few of them will ever be used.

The only time I have ever needed to precompute a lot if data like this is to store a list of "closest locations" for each location in the database, and that can be done with a much smaller table. (and even that isn't always necessary, as you can sometimes get the same data with a bounding box query)

If you're set on this architecture, have you considered using the table as a cache, to store the results as people ask for them, and them having it be the first place that your application looks for an answer when a new query arrives?

Comment: Funnily enough that had crossed my mind as an alternative, and would kind of make sense because, users will invariably be viewing ads from similar locations so the data is already fetched and stored. Ive seen quite a few sites, use a base location ( as the from ) and the seller location as the to .. and I am pretty sure that is fetched via sql. Example of which : http://brisbane.gumtree.com.au/f-Jobs-graphic-web-design-Logan-Area-Bethania-W0QQCatIdZ18470QQLocationZ3005932